# SQL Server Compare two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, each has 1 column:

If all of Table B's rows are contained within Table A, such as

```
TABLE A ('A')
       ,('B')
       ,('C')
       ,('D')

TABLE B ('B')
       ,('C')
```

Then, let the variable @In = 1

Otherwise, if Table B contains rows that are not in A, Let @In = 0

How can I do this?

Comment: Look at using EXISTS and/or NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B 
           EXCEPT
           SELECT * FROM A)
    SET @In = 0
ELSE
    SET @In = 1
```

See here for documentation on EXCEPT and INTERSECT: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188055.aspx

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2005+ of course!

**EDIT:** Fixed my reverse logic on the assignment of 0/1 (whoops!).
See SQL Fiddle here for a working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9769/4

**EDIT 2:** Swapped tables A and B in EXISTS clause after clarification.

Comment: It does not work.  I used the same Idea to store the data in a temp table first, but it did not work either.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for spotting my error @NeilP. I've updated the answer and provided a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Beercohol, Thanks for the help.  When I switch between 0 and 1, the query always gives me one value, either 0 or 1.

Comment: Hi @user1816353, are you saying that the query always returns the same value whether or not the tables are different?

I've created a second SQL fiddle here that shows an example of when the tables are the same, and it returns the opposite value to the first one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a643/1/0
The only difference between the two are the inserts that populate the tables.

Comment: beercohol, I post the query below.  Can you please check it for me?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select case when count(*) > 0 then 0 else 1
from a full outer join b on a.a = b.b
where a.a = null or b.b= null
```

Comment: Thanks Neil, but it does not give me the correct answer.

Comment: It should do, you could change the case statement to show the rows to identify where it is going wrong. Does you data contain mixed cases? Your database might be set to be case or accent sensitive and therefore things that should match, do not.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Neil's suggestion (It works):

```
create table A (col varchar(10))
create table B (col varchar(10))
declare @InT Int, @InB Int, @In Int

INSERT INTO A VALUES 
    ('A')
   ,('B')
   ,('C')
   ,('D')

INSERT INTO B VALUES  
    ('B')
   ,('C')
   ,('Z')

select @InT =  count(*) from A join B on A.col = B.col
select @InB =  count(*) from B

IF (@InT = @InB)
  SET @In = 1
Else
  SET @In = 0

print '@In = ' + CAST(@In As VARCHAR(10))
print '@InT = ' + CAST(@InT As VARCHAR(10))
print '@InB = ' + CAST(@InB As VARCHAR(10))

DROP TABLE A
DROP TABLE B
```

Comment: Please see my updated answer - I got the 1 and 0 round the wrong way, sorry!

Comment: Yes that should work, but note that it would not scale easily or nicely if multiple columns were involved!
EXISTS with EXCEPT will work for any number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Beercohol's query. (I still get the same @In if I uncomment the table B's Z.

```
create table A (col varchar(10))
create table B (col varchar(10))
DECLARE @In INT

INSERT INTO A VALUES 
    ('A')
   ,('B')
   ,('C')
   ,('D')

INSERT INTO B VALUES  
    ('B')
   ,('C')
 --  ,('Z')


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A 
       EXCEPT
       SELECT * FROM B)
   SET @In = 0
ELSE
   SET @In = 1

PRINT @In
DROP TABLE A
DROP TABLE B
```

Comment: Yes that will always return zero, because the tables are **different**, which is what `EXCEPT` tests for. I thought that was what you were asking! Your question is not clearly worded.
If you want to check that there are no rows in table B that are not also contained in A (regardless of what else is in A), then use Neil's answer.

Comment: Ok sorry, I've thought about it a bit more, and you can achieve your desired result simply by swapping tables A and B with the EXCEPT.
I've updated my answer again, please try it!

With updated fiddle too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9769/5/0